# How to fix the ESLint expected indentation of N spaces but found Y issue?

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, eslint

I installed a React.js project from a git repository but when I try to modify any code by creating new line or just copy/past a piece of code, my IDE (PhpStorm) gives me the following error  :

`ESLint expected indentation of 2 spaces but found 4`

[image: S]

More info :

1. IDE: PhpStorm
2. OS: Windows 10
3. This project was developed in Linux

Answer (score 0):

Please try importing code style preferences from ESLint configuration per instructions at https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2019.3/eslint.html#ws_js_linters_eslint_import_code_style_from_eslint and then re-format the code with **Code | Reformat code**